# Problem with Ajax date select onchange value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use AJAX on date_select the value pass as parameter only the value that was changed
but I need the values of each field too.

Example

DATESELECT

5 June 2011 => Change to 6 June 2011 but AJAX VALUE only pass in params the value "6".

I need the day, month and year.

My code
The View
    <% form_for(@operation, :url => submit_cancellation_admin_operation_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>

```
  <p>Fecha de Pago:<br/><br/>
    <%= date_select("", :payment_date,  {:start_date => Time.now - 10}, {:onchange =>"#{remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'operations', :action => "update_payment_date"}, :with => "'payment_date='+value")}"}) %>
  </p>

<%  end  %>
```

The Controller

```
  def cancel
    @operation        = Operation.find(params[:id])
    last_pagare       = Pagare.find(:first, :conditions => "operation_id = #{@operation.id} AND state <> 'cancelled'")
    #The condition unless is because the last_pagare could be nil if the operation is totally cancelled 
    @punitive_ammount = @operation.get_punitive(DateTime.now.to_date, last_pagare.expiration_date.to_date) unless last_pagare.nil?
  end

  def update_payment_date
    #Here I take the params 
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Please I need to resolve how solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jQuery to solve this problem. best solutions to listen (or read) your suggestions (Excuse I use Google Translate for this phrase).

```
<%= date_select("", :payment_date, {:start_date => Time.now - 10}, {:onchange =>"#{remote_function(:url  => {:controller => 'operations', :action => "update_payment_date", :id=> @operation.id},
                              :with => "'payment_date_1i='+$j('#_payment_date_1i').val()+'&payment_date_2i='+$j('#_payment_date_2i').val()+'&payment_date_3i='+$j('#_payment_date_3i').val()")}"}) %>
```